# How do i do a condition for a callback or rather a .where() function shown below?

Tags: javascript

How do i do a condition for a callback or rather a .where() function shown below? if the condition is true the .where() condition is added.

```
await Firestore.collection(_COLLECTION_NAME)
    .orderBy(orderBy, direction)
    .where("CreatedAt", "<=", TimeStamp.now())
    true && .where("") << how do I put a condition here?
    .limit(1)
    .get(),
```

Answer (score 2):

Split the code into a few sections, saving intermediate variables along the way:

```
let query = Firestore.collection(_COLLECTION_NAME)
    .orderBy(orderBy, direction)
    .where("CreatedAt", "<=", TimeStamp.now())
if (condition) {
  query = query.where(/* something */);
}
await query.limit(1)
  .get();
```